# EF Core migrations script file in Azure Pipelines

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-pipelines, entity-framework-migrations, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm using the below `.yaml` task for the migrations. The task is successfully completed but it generates only the MigrationHistory script. There is no actual script available with the tables.

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Create SQL Scripts'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: ef
    arguments: 'migrations script --output $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/SQL/tododbscript.sql --idempotent --project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/AppService.App/AppService.App.csproj --context NotiDbContext'
```

**Script Generated:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[EFMigrationHistory]') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EFMigrationHistory] (
        [MigrationId] nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
        [ProductVersion] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_EFMigrationHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId])
    );
END;
GO
```

I could run the commandLine in VS and able to generate files. Anything i'm missing ?

Comment: Hi there, May I know if you run the `dotnet ef ` in lcoal **command line prompt** will it generate the sample script?

Comment: Yes it generates the SQL output file

Comment: Glad to know the answer could resolve your issue. You may consider accepting it, which can help others with similar concerns. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same with you, this is because the command runs from the migration, **if there's no migration existing**, it will has the sql script output:

[image]

You can check the `Migration folder` in your devops repo, or use command `dotnet ef migrations list --project project.csproj` to check existing migrations.

To resolve it, you can

1.sync the code(migration folder) from local to your devops repo.

2.or you can create the migration in pipeline.

so that **it has migrations before** `dotnet.exe ef migrations script` command.

My sample below:

```
steps:

- script: 'dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef'
  displayName: Install dotnet EF

- script: 'dotnet ef migrations add 20231110-testmigration --project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\DotNetCoreSqlDb\DotNetCoreSqlDb.csproj'
  displayName: Create test Migration

- script: 'dotnet ef migrations script  --idempotent --output migrations.sql --project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\DotNetCoreSqlDb\DotNetCoreSqlDb.csproj --context MyDatabaseContext'
  displayName: Create EF Scripts
```

The new sql:
[image]

Comment: Also seems i have missed a command, this one works as well. `migrations add InitialMigration --project $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/AppService.App/AppService.App.csproj --context NotiDbContext`

Comment: When this script runs for the second time - like updating the model again it creates the same script file with Create Table and during deployment it says "Table already exist". Any solutions?